# Firestore (4.13.0): INTERNAL UNHANDLED ERROR

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase Functions and use Firestore inside. This error now comes up when I try to access a collectionRef with a query.

```
let accountRef = firebase.firestore().collection('/accounts');
            accountRef.where("_username", "==", username).get().then((snapshot) => {...})
```

this is the stack I am getting on Firebase Console

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ns' of null
at Object.load (/user_code/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/grpc/index.js:146:28)
at loadProtos (/user_code/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:6060:17)
at NodePlatform.loadConnection (/user_code/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:6084:22)
at FirestoreClient.initializeRest (/user_code/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14077:14)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:13968:54
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: the bug has been fixed, upgrade to 4.13.1.

Downgrade to 4.12, it looks like this is a bug in the js sdk: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/711

Comment: Thank you very much for founding this!

Comment: It looks as though this has now been fixed in 4.13.1